# Build Tree From Text

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, treeview

I have data on my PHP and I will make a tree menu from this data:

```
$data[] = "IT/managerial/software/kasubsie/Moro/Konsolidasi Server";
$data[] = "IT/managerial/software/kasubsie/Moro/Setting Server";
$data[] = "IT/managerial/software/kasubsie/Setting Server/Moro";
```

How to generate into table with columns:

```
| id | parent_id | name |
```

Comment: Which is `id`? Which is `parent_id`? Which is `name`?

Answer (score 1):

This works. Build on this. Main logic is to `preg_split` each row of data. Hope this helps!

```
<?php

$data = array();
$data[] = "IT/managerial/software/kasubsie/Moro/Konsolidasi Server";
$data[] = "IT/managerial/software/kasubsie/Moro/Setting Server";
$data[] = "IT/managerial/software/kasubsie/Setting Server/Moro";

$value_array = array();

echo '<table border="1">';
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $value_array = preg_split("/\//", $value);
    foreach ($value_array as $table_cell_value) {
        echo '<td>' . $table_cell_value . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```